# Passing a very large json object to mvc4 controller

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4

I've had a look and I can't seem to get this to work and I constantly get the error message that my json object is too large to pass to my controller.

**`The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.`**

So I have a json object that contains the base64 string of up to 3 images as well as some textual data.

I am trying to pass that object to the controller.  It works fine if I do not include the images.

So I have tried, in web.config;

```
<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
        <webServices>
            <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="500000000"/>
        </webServices>
    </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

as well as;

```
<add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="150000000" />
```

I have changed my controller from an ActionResult to a JsonResult.

I've read that I need to create my own json parser etc and a lot of the sites deal with passing data from the controller to the client.

I am trying to get a large amount of data from the client to the controller.

Any help here?

Comment: Changing `ActionResult` to `JsonResult` should not make any difference (that specifies the type of data that is sent from the controller to the view). Is there a reason you need to post your images as json rather than using `FormData`?

Comment: I can't use formdata as there is already a parent form that some bright spark created for [all] web pages a couple years ago and i do not have the scope to redesign all this spaghetti.

Comment: That should not stop you from using `FormData` to post your 3 files. - `var formdata = new FormData()` then append each of your files and post using the technique [shown here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293637/how-to-append-whole-set-of-model-to-formdata-and-obtain-it-in-mvc/29293681#29293681)

Comment: OK, so the files were selected on another screen and are now in Base64

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the source code ASP.NET MVC for the `JsonResult` class, you find this code ([+](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/JsonResult.cs)):

```
if (Data != null)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    if (MaxJsonLength.HasValue)
    {
        serializer.MaxJsonLength = MaxJsonLength.Value;
    }
    if (RecursionLimit.HasValue)
    {
       serializer.RecursionLimit = RecursionLimit.Value;
    }
    response.Write(serializer.Serialize(Data));
}
```

The defualt values for `MaxJsonLength` property is set to 2MB and `RecursionLimit` is set to 100.
You can change the defualt values this way:

```
return new JsonResult
{
     MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue,
     Data = customers,
     JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
};
```

[more info](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/so-you-need-to-expose-json-endpoints/).